# Evaluating an Expression using MVEL

Tags: java, expression, mvel

I need to evaluate a expression in MVEL containing date. Basically, **I need to add Certain number of days to a given date and get the value.** When I am trying to evaluate the expression in MVEL, getting some exceptions.

Here is my code::

```
package Mvel;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mvel2.MVEL;
import org.mvel2.integration.VariableResolverFactory;
import org.mvel2.integration.impl.MapVariableResolverFactory;

public class Mveldatetest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m1.put("name", "xyz");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date d1 = sdf.parse("02/10/2014");
        m1.put("doj", d1);  
        //Date d2=sdf.parse("05/10/2014");
        System.out.println("Given Date"+" "+d1);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d1);
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
         Date finaldate=(Date)  MVEL.eval("c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4)",m1);

         System.out.println(finaldate);


    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception::

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: unresolvable property or identifier: c]
[Near : {... c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4 ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.getBeanProperty(PropertyAccessor.java:677)
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.getNormal(PropertyAccessor.java:179)
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.get(PropertyAccessor.java:146)
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.get(PropertyAccessor.java:126)
    at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValue(ASTNode.java:187)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:106)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:49)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:165)
    at Mvel.Mveldatetest.main(Mveldatetest.java:31)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `c` to the context `m1`. Also, `Calender` is unknown, too, but you could just use `c` instead (ugly, but works). Finally, note that `add` returns void, i.e. it modifies `c` in-place. Try this:

```
System.out.println(c.getTime());
m1.put("c", c);
MVEL.eval("c.add(c.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4)", m1);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Thu Oct 02 00:00:00 CEST 2014
Mon Oct 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014
```

Comment: Well, i trust you !The reason for my counter question was MVEL documentation, which says you need to mention FQCN in case of java classes used in MVEL expressions !